# Xamarin Forms iOS black box in middle of splash screen on iOS 11 only

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios11

I'm using Xamarin Forms to create iOS app. Only on iOS 11 the app splash screen has a black box in middle instead of an image. I don't know if it is related but this issue started to appear when we changed language on phone to test localisation. I'm using LaunchScreen.storyboard to create my splash screen that comes with Xamarin Forms sample project. Also if I change the image name in LaunchScreen.storyboard the splash screen starts to appear right for a limited time.

I'm using latest VS 2017 15.7.2 and Latest Xcode

Comment: Same thing happens to me sometimes. It sort of just comes and goes and I'm not sure why. You could try cleaning and rebuilding the solution. Sometimes that works for me

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding are not working anymore. I'm worried because this black box also appeared in a production app downloaded from Appstore.

Comment: It may just be that the image is too large to load in the amount of time the splash screen is displayed.  Try using a low res image to see if that helps. You may also want to research the app lifecycle amd how the splash screen plays into that

Comment: Did you solve it? I am experimentig the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, my image for the splash screen was on resource (not assets) folder as a png file.

[image]

In the splashScreen widget, changing the name of image without extension (my_image.png -> my_image) worked for me.